# running uwsgi as master won't handle requests

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I have the following set up

```
src
|
|--flask_app
|--|--controllers.py
|--|--provider.py
|--|--__init__.py
|--config.py
|--wsgi.py
|--myproject.ini
|--myproject.sock
```

**init**.py creates the flask application

```
from flask import Flask, g
from flask_app.controllers import api_module
from flask_app.provider import CassandraDbProvider


# Define WSGI application object

app = Flask(__name__)

# Configure it

app.config.from_object('config')

cassandra = CassandraDbProvider(**app.config['DATABASE_CONNECT_OPTIONS'])



@app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.db = cassandra


app.register_blueprint(api_module)
```

controler.py has the views that run on endpoints and also creates the blueprint

Finally wsgi.py has the following code

```
from cassandra_flask_app import app as application

if __name__ == "__main__":
application.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)
```

myproject.ini

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi

logto = /var/log/uwsgi/uwsgi.log

threads = 10

socket = myproject.sock
chmod-socket = 664
vacum = true

die-on-term = true
```

Upstart script

```
description "uWSGI server instance configured to serve myproject"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

setuid myuser
setgid www-data

env PATH=/home/myuser/myproject/myprojectenv/bin
chdir /home/myuser/myproject/src
exec uwsgi --ini myproject.ini
```

and nginx

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myIpHere;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/home/myuser/myproject/src/myproject.sock;
    }
}
```

controller.py

```
api_module = Blueprint('my_api', __name__, prefix='/api') # this might be wrong now because I don't have code infront of me

#myvmip/api/ works fine when uwsgi is master
@api_module.route('/', methods=['GET']):
def test_url():
    return 'c'

#myvmip/api/normal_view/?query1=some_value" doesn't work when in master with no error. Only connection timeout error in nginx error.log.
@api_module.route('/nomral_view/', methods=['GET'])
def normal_view():
    get_parameter = request.args.get('query1')
    #uses g.db to connect to database and fetch some results
    #database is cassandra db
    return jsonify(**json)
```

It runs good on my developement machine. On my vm I load my flask application using nginx and uwsgi. I have set up uwsgi as described on many tutorial on the internet. The problem is that If I run uwsgi as master then It won't access some of my urls. Disabling it works properly. What do you think it could be? Does it matter uwsgi isn't loaded as master?

Comment: Do you have any uWSGI error logs?

Comment: Uwsgi has a ton of options.  Please post your ini file (or command line parameters) you're using.

Comment: @iurisilvio no error logs, just time out. It looks like it doesn't reach uwsgi.

Comment: It's a good question, but missing some critical pieces of information. `some of my urls` -> which urls. We need view code for these urls. We need Nginx logs. We need UWSGI logs.

Comment: Try running uWSGI from the terminal directly, not from upstart to see if you get more output.

Comment: Also try to telnet to uWSGI port to see if it responds.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa i use sock file to for the interconnection between nginx and uWSGI. How can I telnet to uWSGI? Also I tried and executed uWSGI directy. The same: When in master, no messages at all not even showing it handled the request.

Comment: Looks like you are using UNIX sockets. Try to see if the socket is alive using this http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/46107/14115 Or switch to TCP/IP and then you can telnet to the port like `telnet localhost 1234`.

Comment: Here is example of using TCP/IP socket instead of UNIX socket https://github.com/miohtama/LibertyMusicStore/blob/master/conf/uwsgi.ini#L2

Comment: It might be some sort of UNIX permission issue with socket. nginx, uwsgi running different UNIX users. If this is the case you might try to fix the permisions of socket file or switch to localhost TCP/IP.

Comment: Αnd the same in the nginx file in uwsgi_pass;

Comment: What it troubles me the most is that it works when I deactivate master option..

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following to your myproject.ini file

```
chdir = /path/to/project
callable = application
```

http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html#deploying-flask

Also if you have a virtualenv you should add

```
venv=/path/to/venv
```

Comment: I set the env in the Upstart file. I used this tutorial here https://goo.gl/wM3zP1